# Views Ticker is not scrolling the text continuously

Tags: views

I am using [Views Ticker](https://drupal.org/project/views_ticker) module to display continuous auto scrolling news. Although currently I have only 3 news items but I have configured it to show 5 news items under pager option. I am facing following issues with it-

1. For the first time, News are scrolling completely but later on this block becomes empty and news displays again only when i click on this block
2. News items are duplicating frequently. I mean it is showing the same news multiple times.

My objective is just to display some text automatically scrolling vertically infinite times.

Comment: same here.. Any solution???

Comment: @GIRI: No solution. The problem seems intermittent. Let me know if you find any solution. Thanks :)

Comment: this module is really disgusting. I even poked to the maintainers but there was no action...

Comment: Is there any alternate module to perform this action??? @Ravi Joshi